# error : Element <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet> has an invalid value of "NoExtensions"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to open a C++ project by others under VS2010 in Windows XP on a virtual machine. The problem is, the project was seem to be developed under VS2012 under Windows7 I think. I have successfully converted its related configurations, thanks to internet. But now, when I try to build this project, I got the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(147,5): error : Element <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet> has an invalid value of "NoExtensions".
```

Seems like the configuration changes caused this problem. What I did is to change the `Project ->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Platform Toolset` from "v120" to "v100", then also changed the `DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0` into `DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0"`.

How can I overcome this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I solved it by this way: `Project ->Properties ->C/C++ ->Code Generation->Enable Enhanced Instruction Set -> Not Set`.

Comment: Alternatively, this can be done by searching and replacing `<EnableEnhancedInstructionSet(\s[^>]+)?>NoExtensions</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>` with `<EnableEnhancedInstructionSet\1>NotSet</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>` in all `.sln`, `.*proj` and `.props` files.

Comment: Just a heads-up. This problem also occurs when you develop a project in VS 2010 and then later opens it in a higher version of VS(say. VS 2017), complies it but forget to retarget the platform toolset.